# Oracle SQL creating crosstab using merge

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, crosstab

I need help creating crosstab.
I was told that it can be done using Merge statement, but I feel quite confused about it.
Maybe someone had expirience in using merge statement to create crosstab.

Here is the initial table:
(there can be many persons in initial table and many columns in result table)

```
person  text
person_1    some_text_1
person_1    some_text_2
person_1    some_text_3
person_1    some_text_4
person_1    some_text_5
person_2    some_text_6
person_2    some_text_7
person_2    some_text_8
person_2    some_text_9
```

And table I need as result:

```
person_1    person_2
some_text_1 some_text_6
some_text_2 some_text_7
some_text_3 some_text_8
some_text_4 some_text_9
some_text_5
```

UPD: I know it can be done with pivot or smth else.
The question is how to do it using MERGE.

Comment: Why is what you've tried already confusing you? Are you able to post your code and your explanation of what you don't understand?

Comment: I don't think the MERGE statement is what you want to use. The is to perform a conditional insert/update based on criteria.

Comment: >Why is what you've tried already confusing you?
I don't know what key should I use to link PERSONS and REPORT.

  `MERGE INTO REPORT
  USING (SELECT PERSON, TEXT FROM PERSONS)
  ON (--on what condition?)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (--how can I define only one column     to insert?)
  VALUES (TEXT);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to get it using 'merge'.Actually,I don't think 'merge' can work...
Here is my solution which can satisfy your need but not convenient...

```
SELECT A.TEXT AS PERSON_1,B.TEXT AS PERSON_2...
FROM 
(SELECT TEXT,ROWNUM AS R  FROM PERSON_TAB WHERE PERSON='person_1') A
FULL JOIN 
(SELECT TEXT,ROWNUM AS R FROM PERSON_TAB WHERE PERSON='person_2' ) B
ON A.R=B.R
FULL JOIN
...
```

If you have too many "persons",you can create a proceture to do that.
Please tell me,If you have known how to do it using merge or better ways :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try with a combination of [RANK](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions141.htm#i1269223) and [PIVOT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/analysis.htm#DWHSG0209) like this

```
select person_1,person_2
from (
        select *
        from (
                select rank() over(partition by person order by text) as idx, person, text
                from <your_table>
            )
        pivot (
                max(text) for person in (
                        'person_1' as person_1,
                        'person_2' as person_2
                    )
            )
    )
```